High-CPU-usage issues in SQL Server, got the query but trying to find the parameter thats passed in so can locate the issue?
I've been having some big problems with 100% CPU usage at intermittent times, but recently getting worse as it's a shared database which is used for both Intranet applications and an external large multi-tenancy web CMS platform.
I have have used the following query from Microsoft to find the query

SELECT TOP 10 s.session_id,
           r.status,
           r.cpu_time,
           r.logical_reads,
           r.reads,
           r.writes,
           r.total_elapsed_time / (1000 * 60) 'Elaps M',
           SUBSTRING(st.TEXT, (r.statement_start_offset / 2) + 1,
           ((CASE r.statement_end_offset
                WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(st.TEXT)
                ELSE r.statement_end_offset
            END - r.statement_start_offset) / 2) + 1) AS statement_text,
           COALESCE(QUOTENAME(DB_NAME(st.dbid)) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(st.objectid, st.dbid)) 
           + N'.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(st.objectid, st.dbid)), '') AS command_text,
           r.command,
           s.login_name,
           s.host_name,
           s.program_name,
           s.last_request_end_time,
           s.login_time,
           r.open_transaction_count
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions AS s
JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests AS r ON r.session_id = s.session_id CROSS APPLY sys.Dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) AS st
WHERE r.session_id != @@SPID
ORDER BY r.cpu_time DESC


This has helped me find the query that's causing the issue and also to build an index that should help the issue.
The query it has returned is this;
(@P1 varchar(5))SELECT a.id_e, a.path, a.filename, a.width, a.height, b.name AS type, c.name AS object, image_number
                    FROM ila.dbo.images a
                    JOIN ila.dbo.image_types b ON a.type = b.id
                    JOIN ila.dbo.image_objects c ON b.object = c.id
                    WHERE a.sid = @P1 and b.name in ('info', 'thumbnail', 'source', 'original', 'large', 'main', 'main_large', 'main_extra_large', 'extra_large') ORDER BY a.image_number ASC

What would really help me to do this is if I could get SQL Server to actually tell me what the @P1 param that is being passed in, this is a unique site identifier and PK.
Is there anyway to modify the original query from Microsoft so that the actual @P1 param value, will be shown when query ran?

None of the answers there appear to be on the right track. Unless you are lucky and the value that the query is running with is the same one as the plan was compiled with.  From an actual execution plan you would need to get it out of the ParameterRuntimeValue- maybe this shows up in a "live" execution plan as retrieved by dm_exec_query_statistics_xml  or the plan retained with the LAST_QUERY_PLAN_STATS option - I'm not sure

Looks like it can appear in dm_exec_query_statistics_xml but maybe not by default depending on what @@VERSION you are on! https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/kb5017788-fix-parameterruntimevalue-is-missing-from-the-showplan-xml-when-you-use-the-dmv-sys-dm-exec-query-statistics-xml-38fa5497-fc51-4063-9478-196ebc308b0f

I'm not sure why it would help you if you get the parameter value? What index do you think will fix the issue?

Please add a tag for the version you are using as looks like details vary and SQL Server 2022 has FORCE_SHOWPLAN_RUNTIME_PARAMETER_COLLECTION instead of trace flag 2446

@siggemannen - The param would tell me what site ID was calling the querying and thus allow me to find what template the site was using so I could find query and possibly re-write (it's a multi-tenancy web CMS platform that runs 1000's of sites through shared DB / codebase).
I used the built in index "generator" to create / cover the missing index, wasn't sure how long it would take to create 26 mins it turned out and thinking the query / code change may have been quicker.

@MartinSmith embarrassingly SQL Server 2008 (yes I know archaic, but I'm the managing director of company, lead and 1 of only 2 developers and handle all infrastructure plus wear many other hats). I am currently migrating from DC to Azure so everything will be back on present day software / platforms once completed.

Ah right so none of dm_exec_query_statistics_xml or the LAST_QUERY_PLAN_STATS option are available anyway!

As the other query from Microsoft, when ran suggested the correct index to build / cover it has solved my issue, so I'll mark this as closed / answered as no longer need to locate the param value. It has reduced CPU usage from 60-70% normal and spikes / peaks at 100% to around 20-30% normal 50-60% spikes / peaks so looks like has been an issue for some time!
Thanks everyone for your time and input!

@MartinSmith no but managed to solve by creating index and then locating query in code also. Thanks again for your time / replies!
